# Perl DBG begin_work() is not preventing commits

Tags: mysql, perl, commit

I'm getting really confused with how the autocommit functionality is supposed to work with dbh. The following code inserts data into the table just fine but it's still doing it 1 row at a time. What I was expecting was that when using the `begin_work()`, it would wait until the loop was complete and then commit when it gets to `$dbh->commit()`.

Any clues?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;

open(FILE, "<attr.csv");

$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:mydb;host=myserver:3306',
       'myuser', 'mypass', { RaiseError => 1 })
or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

$sqlinsert='INSERT INTO ATTR (ID, IDSECCLASS, AttrName, Attrref, Objname, AttrType,
            FQname) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';

$upd = $dbh->prepare($sqlinsert);
$dbh->begin_work()  or die $dbh->errstr;
while ($line = <FILE>) {
    @row = split(/,/, $line);
    $upd->execute(@row) or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
}

$dbh->commit();

close(FILE);
```

Comment: 1) Always `use strict; use warnings;` 2) Not the cause of your issue, but it would be cleaner to set `AutoCommit` in the `connect` statement: `my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass, { AutoCommit => 0 });` You certainly don't need to disable `AutoCommit` *after* calling `begin_work()`, which [turns it off anyway](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#begin_work). 3) The MyISAM storage engine doesn't support transactions, so if you're using it, changing `AutoCommit` will have no effect. MyISAM was the default before MySQL 5.5.5.

Comment: You're definitely correct. I'm using MyISAM. What should I set it to?

Comment: If you want to improve throughput, you may want to try load data.

Comment: Use InnoDB. And as @Tim3880 said, if all you're doing is loading a CSV file, [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) would be much faster.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm not too familiar with Stored procs. How would I call a stored proc from my Perl script? (or that could just be my next search ;) )

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` isn't a stored procedure, just a regular statement like `SELECT`. You can call it from your Perl script like this: `$dbh->do('LOAD DATA INFILE ...');`

Comment: This was brilliant. The difference is load time was huge! Thank you! 20k rows took maybe less than 5 seconds to load as opposed to 11 minutes. FYI, after switching to InnoDB, I tired the intermittent commits (every 500 records), the load times were exactly the same as 1 rec at a time, I was expecting a big difference but I didn't see any. Thanks for all the help, I think he "LOAD DATA LOCAL FILE" statement is going to be part of my regular toolset going forward.